# Writing to pipe blocks in some cases

Tags: pipe, ocaml, fork, ipc

I am trying to set up a two-way parent-child communication using pipes, in particular between my process and an smt solver (Z3). My code (in OCaml) seems to work in many cases, but sometimes write from my process to the solver will block.

Btw in case you need some help reading the OCaml code, documentation for the OCaml unix functions I used can be found here:
http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatUnix.html

```
let (solver_in, main_out) = BatUnix.pipe ~cloexec:false () in
(* pipe that solver writes to and parent reads from *)
let (main_in, solver_out) = BatUnix.pipe ~cloexec:false () in

(* Solver should not get the descriptors used by parent to read and write *)
BatUnix.set_close_on_exec main_in;
BatUnix.set_close_on_exec main_out;

let pid = BatUnix.create_process solver (Array.of_list (solver :: params))
          solver_in solver_out solver_out in

(* Parent should close the descriptors used by the solver *)
BatUnix.close solver_in;
BatUnix.close solver_out;
let cin = Unix.in_channel_of_descr main_in in
set_binary_mode_in cin false;
let cout = Unix.out_channel_of_descr main_out in
set_binary_mode_out cout false
```

This is the code I use to write to the solver's pipe:
   output_string cout question;
   flush cout

The workflow involved is that I send a query to the solver, get an answer, then depending on the answer I may send it another query or not (it's kind of hard to include code for that unfortunately). In many cases, this has worked well, I've managed to do some back and forth with the solver.
I was trying the a pretty large example, and while I can send a (huge) query to the solver, and then read the reply, when I try to send the second (which btw is smaller in size than the first one) query the write blocks. If I try to send a small string it will work, or if I split the new query into two, the first half doesn't get blocked but the second half gets blocked.

It seems that the solver has stopped reading for some reason. I am also spitting out everything in a separate text file which Z3 handles perfectly well without crashing or anything. How do I approach debugging this?

EDIT: Based on Goswin von Brederlow's answer, I think I can roughly see why this is happening. I am feeding a huge query, but I am not asking for the solver to do anything, I am just sending constraints. Then I send one more constraint asking the solver to solve it, and block waiting for the answer which is not immediate. This all works fine, because the parent and the solver are not trying to talk at the exact same time. 
The problem is when I ask for the model, where I send a bunch of queries for which the solver answers immediately (I don't have to explicitly ask for an answer at the end), and while I am still sending queries the solver is sending back answers. I was thinking that since the solver is reading from the pipe it should clear, but I am probably writing faster than the solver can read and process the pipe data. I could use non-blocking IO, but that would probably require me to mess up the logic of my program. I'll try to spawn another thread either to do the writing (and hence the main process continues until it reaches the part where it starts reading from the solver) or spawn another thread to read just before starting to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are usually two problems communicating with pipes:

1) As Jeffrey Scofield mentioned in his answer the output to a pipe isn't flushed so it is never actually written to the pipe. This only happens with buffered IO but that is what ocamls channels are.

2) Both parties try to write to the pipe and block so none get around to reading. It's a classic deadlock.

> It seems that the solver has stopped reading for some reason.

As you flush your end of the pipe this seems to point at the second case being the problem. You are feeding the solver with problems and have filled the pipes buffer. So your process blocks waiting for the solver to read from the pipe. On the other side the solver is writing back infos, progress or solutions and has also filled the other pipes buffer. It is now blocked waiting for you to read back the output. A classic deadlock.

Using the high level channels I'm afraid there might be only one solution. Create a second thread to read back the output. Alternatives would be using the low level API for file descriptors and setting `main_out` to non-blocking or using asynchronous IO like that provided by LWT.

Comment: I think I see why 2 is happening. In the first case, even though I am feeding a huge query, I am not asking for the solver to do anything, I am just sending constraints. Then I send one more constraint asking the solver to solve it, and block waiting for the answer. This all works fine, because the parent and the solver are not trying to talk at the exact same time.

Answer (score 0):

The usual problem with using pipes to communicate with a process written by somebody else is that their code doesn't flush the output at appropriate moments. You are flushing your output, but there is every likelihood that the solver isn't doing the same. The usual behavior of Unix stdio is not to flush output by lines unless the output is going to a terminal (not a pipe).

It might help to see the command that you are issuing to start up the solver. If it's not a process that you wrote yourself, I'd say that this is likely to be the problem.

Comment: This is the command starting the solver: 
   `let pid = BatUnix.create_process solver (Array.of_list (solver :: params))
          solver_in solver_out solver_out in`